# Approaching multiple categories and selections in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, if-statement

I just wanted to have some input on what the best solution - efficient would be for the problem that follows below.

For instance, say I have 6 different categories. Within these categories, you have 5 to 6 selections. Based on what you choose in each category, a different result is produced. Would you solve this by doing lots of if logic, arrays, or some other method?

My thoughts were to do switch statements or if logic. Is this the best way?

Comment: It would depend. Can you only make one selection from all of the categories, or can you make one selection from each category?

Comment: It would be one selection from each of the categories.

Comment: I suggest creating a **big** `if/elseif` algorithm.

Comment: Those were my thoughts Dugi, but I was wondering if there was a better way possibly.

Comment: Not anything I can think of. Maybe the pros of this website have better thoughts than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you did a layout such as this:

```
switch($cat1){
  case 1:
    switch($cat2){
      case 1:
        ...
        break;
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    ...
    break;
}
```

or this:

```
if($cat1 == 1){
  if($cat2 == 1){
    ...
  }elseif($cat2 == 2){
    ...
  }
}elseif($cat1 == 2){
  ...
}
```

it would take you well over 100,000 lines of code to handle the logic either way. Yikes. But if you have 6 categories each with 6 selections, that gives you a total of 46,656 different combinations. 6^6. If your site is hooked up to a database you could do something like this to help you out.

```
$layout = $cat1 . $cat2 . $cat3 . $cat4 . $cat5 . $cat6;
//making $layout 315632 or whatever based on what they select.
```

And in your database, you could create a table where the id matches up with $layout and you save your display information in rows in the database.

```
 -------------------------------------
|   id   | name | make | year | model |
|--------|------|------|------|-------|
| 111111 | Aero |  S2  | 2011 | M-110 |
| 111112 | .... | .... | .... | ..... |
| 111113 | .... | .... | .... | ..... |
 -------------------------------------
```

Then use a simple row lookup to get your results in php. Of course it would take quite a while to put all of your information into a database but its gonna take quite a while to create the logic in the php file anyways. This would be the fastest way as far as when the user is actually using your site, and it will make it easier for you to debug.

If you aren't able to do this, the next fastest bet (if you can keep it all straight) is to have a 6 nested if/elseif statement. The most checks this would give you would be 36 but it could be less depending on what the user selects. A switch-case would also work but they're a little messier than an if/elseif statement.

Comment: Thanks for the thought out answer Aust.